# How to compute this Conditional Expectation involving a Gaussian vector?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

Given a real number $a\ne 0$ and two **independent** $\mathbb R^d$ valued random variables $X$ and $Y$ with $Y\sim\mathcal N(\mu_Y,\Sigma_Y)$ ($X$'s dsitribution is unknown), I am trying to find a measurable function $f:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ which solves
$$\min_{f \text{ measurable}} \mathbb E_{X,Y}\left[|f(X + aY) - Y|^2\right] \tag1$$

Well, if I denote $Z:=X + aY$ it is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#L2_random_variables) that the solution of $(1)$ is given by $f^* : z \mapsto \mathbb E[Y\mid Z = z]$. Therefore my problem boils down to finding the expression of $f^*$, which I have tried doing in the following way :

Given that $X + aY = z $, we have $\mathbb E[X\mid Z = z] + a\mathbb E[Y\mid Z = z] = z$, i.e.$$f^*(z) = \frac{z-\mathbb E[X\mid Z = z]}{a} $$

But I don't know how to compute $\mathbb E[X\mid Z = z]$. I have seen [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30588/deriving-the-conditional-distributions-of-a-multivariate-normal-distribution) and [this post on stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/585858/expected-value-of-x-given-xy-s) which seem to give a solution in case where both $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian, but in my case $X$ is actually not Gaussian (it can be taken to be a Gaussian mixture if that helps).

Is it possible to find a closed-form for $f^*$ in terms of the moments of $X$ and $Y$ ?